# Python How to convert json to python class objects, similar to Object Mapper in Jackson

Tags: python, json, objectmapper

How to convert JSON data to class objects?

Similar to what ObjectMapper does in java. Sample Data:

Parent is Course and Books as Child in One to Many relationship.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Course 1",
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Book 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Book 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you already have classes for `Course` and `Books`? When you say "convert to class objects" it's not clear exactly what you mean. Classes are objects in python, but so are *instances* of classes — it's not clear which you are trying to make.

Comment: Yes, I already have classes, want to convert json data to instance of these classes.